# How to write to a Mac OSX read-only filesystem?

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems, mount

I have DMG I need to mount and write a file to.  When I mount it, finder shows the root and all as read-only.

Then I discovered 'mount -w'.  But when I run that, I get 'mount: unknown special file or file system.'

How can I mount this disk image as writable, or force a file into it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Almost all read-only DMGs are actually compressed (`UDZ0` -- see the `hdiutil(1)` man page), so their file format doesn't support simply "flipping a bit" to make them writable.

You could use Disk Utility or

```
hdiutil imageinfo filename.dmg
```

...to see what format your disk image is in. Then you could use Disk Utility or something like

```
hdiutil convert filename.dmg -format UDSP -o filename.sparseimage
```

...to convert it to a read-write format. Note that the conversion does not happen in-place, so you'll have to tell it to put the output file on a filesystem that has enough room for an uncompressed copy of all the data from your `.dmg`.

The `.dmg` extension does not guarantee that the image is actually compressed, but that's by far the most likely possibility.

There are several other possibilities available to you with `hdiutil`.  For instance, if your `.dmg` is actually uncompressed read-only (`UDRO`), it might be possible to force it to mount read-write. Also, if you want to leave your `.dmg` compressed but still want to mount it in a writable fashion, you can mount it with a "shadow file"; all writes actually get written to the shadow file.

**Update**: Other Answers on this Question seem to think `.dmg` always means `UDZ0` which just isn't true. From the `hdiutil(1)` man page, here are the list of internal formats a `.dmg` can have (note that a couple of these can have different *default* filename extensions like `.sparseimage`, but I'm pretty sure that's not a hard-and-fast rule either).

```
UDRW - UDIF read/write image  
UDRO - UDIF read-only image  
UDCO - UDIF ADC-compressed image  
UDZO - UDIF zlib-compressed image  
UDBZ - UDIF bzip2-compressed image (OS X 10.4+ only)  
UFBI - UDIF entire image with MD5 checksum  
UDRo - UDIF read-only (obsolete format)  
UDCo - UDIF compressed (obsolete format)  
UDTO - DVD/CD-R master for export  
UDxx - UDIF stub image  
UDSP - SPARSE (grows with content)  
UDSB - SPARSEBUNDLE (grows with content; bundle-backed)  
RdWr - NDIF read/write image (deprecated)  
Rdxx - NDIF read-only image (Disk Copy 6.3.3 format)  
ROCo - NDIF compressed image (deprecated)  
Rken - NDIF compressed (obsolete format)  
DC42 - Disk Copy 4.2 image
```

Comment: I didn't assume UDZ0, but all of the types except UDRW, and UDSP (maybe UDxx UDSB or UDT0) are read only. I assumed that all dmgs were compressed with SOMETHING, and so not writable... I've never knowingly come across a NON-compressed DMG...

Comment: @Brian - I use an encrypted UDSP routinely for storing sensitive information on my laptop (passwords, bank info, etc).

Comment: Hey this helped alot, thanks! I found a super easy way to do this, take a look at my answer. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @MaxFelker Glad my suggestion of using a shadow file helped you. Thanks for spelling out one good way of doing it.

Comment: Super useful, +1 my dude!

Answer (score 5):

Here is method I just used for a project and was by far the best way to do this. Found it here:

http://myjeeva.com/best-possible-way-edit-read-only-dmg.html

Attach read-only dmg file using hdiutil

```
hdiutil attach -owners on /path/to/your.dmg -shadow
```

Modify your DM. Use the command line to add, edit or delete contents - doing it in the GUI can have weird side effects or permission issues. Additionally, you may need to *sudo* the commands

Detach mounted drive by below command or Eject it from Finder

```
# fill disk number at <number>
hdiutil detach /dev/disk<number>
```

Converting/Writing a shadowed dmg into read-only DMG

```
hdiutil convert -format UDZO -o /path/to/new.dmg /path/to/your.dmg -shadow
```

Comment: I'm on Sierra and this doesn't work for me.  It creates the ".shadow" file and mounts the dmg, but the mounted drive is still readonly.  I even tried making the .dmg writable and verified that the .shadow file was writeable.

Answer (score 1):

if there's enough "space" on the Rd-onry DMG, you can convert to a R/W DMG using Disk Utility, and convert it back to a compressed DMG if you want. Otherwise, you can "expand" the DMG using hdiutil

Answer (score -2):

You can't write to a DMG. it makes no sense. You need to copy everything out, edit, and make a new DMG.

Sorry.

Comment: That's just not true. You can create read-write .dmg files. Also, you don't need to copy everything out, you can simply convert the disk image to a writable format. See my Answer.

Comment: @Spiff, I suppose, but your solution is EFFECTIVELY the the same as mine, as it has to de-compress, the you add the new file, and re-compress. If it's not in-place, then you're not REALLY writing to the existing DMG...

Comment: Your answer contains false information.

Comment: -1 but if you change the line "You can't write to a DMG" to something that is actually true, like, "You can't write to a readonly DMG" I'll change my vote. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

A regular DMG image is not writable as there's no way to add space to it.  The solution as noted by @Brian_Postow is to copy out the entire contents and create a whole new DMG file.  If you plan to do this a lot, next time create a [sparse image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_image) as these are writable.

Comment: That's not exactly true. The .dmg extension does not necessarily mean that it's read-only. See my Answer.

Comment: I should have said "default" instead of "regular".  Good info on converting them though.